# Get the most repeated post contents from a search?

Tags: posts, sql

In my site the posts content is always the name of a school, so if I search for Chicago I get a lot of posts with different schools as content. What I want to do is to get the Schools with the most posts, so I could display this somewhere:

```
School A - 4
School B - 3
School C - 2
School D - 2
```

(The number at the right is the number of posts the school has)

So what I need to get the most repeated post contents from a particular search including the ones that don't appear in first results page.

I don't know how complicated it can be so if there is no simple way I would be very grateful for just being pointed towards the right direction, so I later figure out how to do it. My site is made with wordpress and the posts are on a SQL database. Please ask if it's not clear or for any more info.

Thanks

Comment: You say the "school" is the post content. How can post content have posts?

Comment: Can you perhaps provide a bare-bones example of what a given post's content may look like? Can each post make references to several schools or just one?

Comment: The content is just the name of a single school/university or idk institute.

Comment: @Lisandro: I think you should make use of [custom taxonomies (Wordpress Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies). Then you can associate a specific school to an article and list / search / weight / rate based on that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your approach is that post's content pretty much ignored in [WordPress query architecture](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). It is meant to be textual information, as opposed to technical meta information.

You have several options:

1. Try to modify raw SQL of query request through filters, such as [`posts_where`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where).
2. Assign school name to [custom field](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) and use [custom fields parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Custom_Field_Parameters) in query (much enhanced in upcoming 3.1 version of WP).
3. As per hakre's suggestion create [custom taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies) and assign schools to posts as its terms.